# Density for a Lebesgue Type Measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Define for $A, B \subset \mathscr B(\mathbb R^{N-1})$ and $C \subset \mathscr B(\mathbb R)$ the following measure on $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb R^{N-1} \times \mathbb R^{N-1} \times \mathbb R)$,
$$K(A \times B \times C):= \lambda^{N-1}(A \cap B)\lambda(C)$$
where $\lambda^k$ is the $k$ dimensional Lebesgue measure.

My question is can we say that
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^{N-1}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{N-1}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,t)f(y,t) \; K(dx,dy,dt) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{N-1}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{N-1}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,t)f(y,t) \; dx \; dy \; dt \; ?$$
If this isnt true, does $K$ have a density? In other words, is there a function $g$ on $\mathbb R^{N-1} \times \mathbb R^{N-1} \times \mathbb R$ such that
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^{N-1}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{N-1}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,t)f(y,t) \; K(dx,dy,dt) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{N-1}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{N-1}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,t)f(y,t) g(x,y,t)\; dx \; dy \; dt \;?$$
Above, $f$ is a function that satisfies
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^{N-1}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{N-1}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,t)f(y,t) \; K(dx,dy,dt) < \infty. $$

Comment: $K$ does not have a density. It is concentrated on $\{(x,y,z): x=y\}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy so K is not absolutely continuous with respect to  Lebesgue measure?

Comment: It is not since it is concentrate on a set of Lebesgue measure $0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I see now, thank you very much.